# Iterative Merge sort not working correctly

Tags: java, sorting, merge, mergesort

I am stuck on this merge sort method. I an not trying to do it recursively but I can't get this one to work for me. I think there is a minor change that needs to be done to get it to work. Any suggestions?

```
  protected static void merge(long[] a, long[] workSpace, int lowPtr, int highPtr, int upperBound) {
    int j = 0;                             // workspace index
    int lowerBound = lowPtr;
    int mid = highPtr-1;
    int n = upperBound-lowerBound+1;       // # of items

    while(lowPtr <= mid && highPtr <= upperBound)
        if(a[lowPtr] < a[highPtr] )
            workSpace[j++] = a[lowPtr++];
        else
            workSpace[j++] = a[highPtr++];

    while(lowPtr <= mid)
        workSpace[j++] = a[lowPtr++];

    while(highPtr <= upperBound)
        workSpace[j++] = a[highPtr++];

    for(j=0; j<n; j++)
        a[lowerBound+j] = workSpace[j];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that it has to do with how you use this routine externally. I could not see an error after 5 minute staring at it, so I tested it and it seems to work fine.

You don't need to know c++ (which is what I happen to have a handy compiler for on this machine)

```
int main() {
    long a[10] = {1,2,3,4,15,5,11,12,13,14}; // two sorted halves to merge
    long * temp = new long[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cout << a[i] << ","; // printout before merge
    }
    cout << endl;
    merge(a, temp, 0, 5, 9); // 0-4 and 5-9
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cout << a[i] << ","; // printout after merge
    }
}
```

output:

```
1,2,3,4,15,5,11,12,13,14,
1,2,3,4,5,11,12,13,14,15,
```

Some more outputs just to convince you:

```
1,2,6,14,15,5,11,12,32,100,
1,2,5,6,11,12,14,15,32,100,

1,2,100,143,1500,5,112,121,320,1000,
1,2,5,100,112,121,143,320,1000,1500,

12,20,100,143,179,5,12,121,320,430,
5,12,12,20,100,121,143,179,320,430,
```